# Different Formulations of Riesz' lemma

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

**Version I**: Let $U$ be a closed subspace of the normed space $X$ with $U \ne X$. Also let $0 < \delta < 1$, then there exists $x_{\delta} \in X$ with $||x_{\delta}|| = 1$ and
$$ 
  || x_{\delta} - u || \ge 1 - \delta
$$
for all $u \in U$.

**Version II:** Let $U$ be a closed subspace of the normed space $X$ with $U \ne X$. Also let $0 < \delta < 1$, then there exists $x_{\delta} \in X$ with $||x_{\delta}|| = 1$ and
$$ 
  || x_{\delta} - u || \ge \delta
$$
for all $u \in U$.

**Version III:**  Let $U$ be a closed subspace of the normed space $X$ with $U \ne X$. Also let $0 < \delta < 1$, then there exists $x_{\delta} \in X$ with $||x_{\delta}|| = 1$ and
$$ 
  || x_{\delta} - u || > \delta
$$
for all $u \in U$.

**Version IV:** Let $U$ be a closed subspace of the normed space $X$ with $U \ne X$. Also let $0 < \delta < 1$, then there exists $x_{\delta} \in X$ with $||x_{\delta}|| = 1$ and
$$ 
  1 \ge || x_{\delta} - u || \ge \delta
$$
for all $u \in U$.

What is the motivation to write 
$$
 ||x_{\delta} - u|| \ge 1 - \delta
$$
instead of 
$$
 ||x_{\delta} - u|| \ge \delta
$$
which in my opinion should be equivalent, as the map $\delta \mapsto 1 - \delta$
is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$, but Version I looks more difficult to me, so we could write for any $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ bijective
$$
 ||x_{\delta} - u|| \ge f(\delta)
$$
which is unneccessary complicated?

Also I collected two other version of the Riesz' Lemma.

Comment: Version 4 is wrong.  Others are trivial reformulations of same thing.

Comment: Version I, as opposed to Version II, emphasises that the lower bound for the norm can be made to be as close to $1$ as you like, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, Version 4 is false, I meant $1 \ge \inf_{u\in U} || x_{\delta} - u || \ge \delta$! @David Mitra: Guess that would be the cause.

Comment: OK, but saying the inf is less than or equal to $1$ doesn't really add anything, because this follows trivially from the facts that $0$ is in $U$ and $\|x_\delta\|=1$.

Comment: Yes, its a trivial fact!